# Elgamal Encryption: Why does Bob get to reuse his keypair while Alice has to generate a new one for every message?

Tags: diffie-hellman, tls, elgamal-encryption, pki

From Christof Paar's book

> The protocol consists of two phases, the classical DHKE (Steps a–f) which is followed by the message encryption and decryption (Steps g and h, respectively). Bob computes his private key $d$ and public key $β$. This key pair does not change, i.e., it can be used for encrypting many messages. Alice, however, has to generate a new public–private key pair for the encryption of every message. Her private key is denoted by $i$ and her public key by $k\,E$. The latter is an ephemeral (existing only temporarily) key, hence the index $E$. The joint key is denoted by $k,M$ because it is used for masking the plaintext.

So why does Bob get to use the same keypair while Alice has to generate a new keypair every time?

Also, in case of TLS/HTTP, between a Browser & a Website - which one is Alice & which one is Bob?

Comment: Is the question about ElGamal or Diffie-Hellman?  The answer differs between the two (and TLS uses DH)

Comment: @poncho - It's about Elgamal - the author talks about DHKE only to say that Elgamal does the same the beginning steps of DHKE

Answer (score 1):

> So why does Bob get to use the same keypair while Alice has to generate a new keypair every time?

Because ElGamal is insecure if Alice picks the same keypair repeatedly.

ElGamal is a public key encryption system; Bob has a long term public key, which he generates once, and hence Bob has to select once private key $b$ and a long term public key $B = G^b$ (note: I don't have the Paar book, hence I don't know what notation he uses).

In contrast, Alice encrypts a message $M$ using Bob's public key $B$; what she does is select a random value $r$ and produce the pair $G^r$ and $M \cdot B^r$.

This is fine; however suppose Alice encrypts a second message $M'$ also to Bob and uses the same random value $r$; this second ciphertext would be $G^r$ and $M' \cdot B^r$.

Why is this bad?  Well, someone seeing both ciphertexts can reconstruct $(M \cdot B^r) (M' \cdot B^r)^{-1} = M \cdot M'^{-1}$. This is more information than we want someone listening in to obtain; in particular, if they happen to know one of the messages (say, $M'$), they can recover the other ($M$).

If Alice selects a fresh random value each time, this does not happen.

Comment: Common, it is a free book [Understanding Cryptography A Textbook for Students and Practitioners](http://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~mbarbulescu/cripto/Understanding%20Cryptography%20by%20Christof%20Paar%20.pdf)